413 Request Entity Too Large file upload ajax call .NET8 deployed on linux server
I am working on .NET8 web application. That is deployed on Linux Server using CI/CD Git actions.
I am having issue while posting a PDF file to server that is of 3MB. Code is working fine on my windows development machine using VS 2022 but giving
413 Request Entity Too Large
When trying to post the file to server.
I have tried all of the following options in the Program.cs to try to increase request limit like following
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.WebHost.UseKestrel(o => o.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 10 * 1024 * 1024);



builder.WebHost.ConfigureKestrel(options =>
    {
        // Set the maximum request body size to 10 MB (or adjust as needed)
        options.Limits.MaxRequestBodySize = 10 * 1024 * 1024; // 10 MB
        
    });



 builder.Services.Configure<IISServerOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.MaxRequestBodySize = 104857600; // 100 MB limit (change as needed)
    });



builder.Services.Configure<FormOptions>(x =>
    {
        x.ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.MultipartBoundaryLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.MultipartHeadersCountLimit = int.MaxValue;
        x.MultipartHeadersLengthLimit = int.MaxValue;
        
    });

But none of them worked.
Added RequestSizeLimit and RequestFormLimits on the action method of the controller as well but did not work.
Following is the controller action method on server side
[RequestSizeLimit(100 * 1024 * 1024)]
[RequestFormLimits(MultipartBodyLengthLimit = 100 * 1024 * 1024)]
[Route("File/Upload")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file, [FromForm] string customFileName)
{
    if (file == null || file.Length == 0)
    {
        return Ok(new { Message = "No file uploaded." });
    }

    return Ok(new { Message = file.FileName });
}

Following is my AJAX Call
function btnuploadfile() {
    $("#prog").show();
    var formData = new FormData();
    var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileUpload');
    const customFileName = document.getElementById('tbxFileName').value.trim();

    if (fileInput.files.length > 0 && customFileName) {
        formData.append('file', fileInput.files[0]);
        formData.append('customFileName', customFileName);
        $.ajax({
            url: '/File/Upload',
            type: 'POST',
            data: formData,
            contentType: false, // Important to set as false for file uploads
            processData: false, // Don't process the data
            success: function (response) {
                // Handle response messages
                $("#prog").hide();
                $('#tbxFileName').val("");
                $('#lblFilePath').html("");
                $('#fileUpload').val('');
                alert(response.message);
            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                alert('File upload failed: ' + textStatus + ', ' + errorThrown);
                $("#prog").hide();
                $('#tbxFileName').val("");
                $('#lblFilePath').html("");
                $('#fileUpload').val('');
            }
        });
    } else {
        alert('Please select a file to upload.');
        $("#prog").hide();
        $('#tbxFileName').val("");
        $('#lblFilePath').html("");
        $('#fileUpload').val('');
    }
}

Please note that all is working fine on my local windows machine. The issue is when deployed on linux.
Nginx or Apache is not being used/installed.
Thank you very much in advance for your help and guidance
